# Is a license required to transmit in the designated aviation band?

Tags: usa, radio-communications

Is an FCC license required for people to operate a radio in the aviation band?

Comment: just need to be clear about the FCC rules

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking about radios in aircraft, on the ground, or both?

Comment: I assume you want to know for people that have a legitimate need to transmit, as indeed if you not involved in a flight activity, you have no right to use the aviation reserved band for transmission.

Comment: When I first learned to fly, I was told that R in the ARROW  mnemonic (https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37657/which-regulations-require-the-arrow-documents/38149) had been a requirement for an FCC radio license in the US until around the early 1980s.  But I don't have a proper cite to confirm this.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but I once tried to find the regulations prohibiting an airline *passenger* from transmitting on airband frequencies, using a call sign such as "Boeing 228UA". I didn't find any such regulations, so I'm not 100% sure that that's actually illegal! (Of course, common sense says it's a bad idea...)

Answer (score 2):

The FCC does not presently require a license for Aviation Radio installations in aircraft, where those are VHF and UHF (as I recall).  These are covered in Part 87 of the FCC regulations.

Travel outside the US requires a station license, and I believe HF transmissions require a license.

Similarly the operator (pilot) needs a permit when traveling outside the US, but does not need the permit within the US, to answer your question about the operator.

Answer (score 1):

When you are the PIC (Pilot in Command) you of course are granted permission to operate those systems as needed as it’s required to properly and in most airspace classes legally fly the craft.

If you own/volunteer/operate at an FBO with it’s own FCC assigned frequency and/or your airport has no control tower and is assigned a ‘Unicom’ frequency (e.g. 122.80 MHz) then you can transmit as needed to dispatch WX info, conditions, etc.

If you have nothing to do with this field or are an avid flight simmer heh..(yes I am too despite flying in real life), then it is illegal to TRANSMIT IN ANYWAY on aviation frequencies (VHF or HF). A license to purchase one is NOT required however.

NOTE:  Some sellers will not sell you an aviation radio (transceiver) without you showing them your license or other authorized certification). That is up to the dealer and is perfectly okay.

The FAA & FCC DOES require you to be Certified (authorized anotherwords) to modify, install, remove, calibrate and ‘sign off’on any piece of avionics equipment involving communications and among other equipment, navigation equipment.

Obtaining certification(s) to install, repair, fix & calibrate 2-way comms (handheld, FBO or in the plane) for aviation can be obtained by attending a certified school or company that offers training & certification.

There are several different types of certifications offered depending on the scope of what you want to do. The basic ‘technician’ can  remove/replace in dash comm systems, however, CANNOT by law troubleshoot it beyond that of the most obvious of adjustments on the front panel switches/options, etc.

Another type of certification is required to actually open it up and bench test it, replace components and calibrate it. It then requires someone to ‘sign off’ on the repairs made and certify it to be ‘air worthy’ so to speak so it can be re-installed. It yet again needs to be signed off on post installation.

Tim Dickerson, CEM, FCC/FAA ACC. 
ARS N9NU
Woodlake Landing (Sandwich, IL)
Unicom: 122.80. ICAO:  IS65 
Commercial License -135 Endorsed

Answer (score 1):

Within the Continental US, no, VHF air band comms do not require a license.  You are required to possess a restricted radiotelephone operator’s permit ($80 and some online paperwork with the FCC) when using command over international waters and while flying in foreign nations.